# Does it exist a word2vec model in french?

Tags: python, word2vec

Is there a pre-trained word2vec model in french language ? The must would be to get it with an api that let me finetune it easily. I was thinking of gensim but can't find such a model in french language.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a number of different models trained on different sets of French data with various parameters here: https://fauconnier.github.io/#data However, they were produced in 2015 already.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of Facebook's published pre-trained `FastText` models: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html

Their text versions, with just whole-word vectors, can be loaded as read-only `KeyedVectors` instances in Gensim. Their full binary models can be loaded as a `FastText` model that (technically) supports additional training, but I've never seen a reliable writeup on how to do such fine-tuning in standard models.

If you think you need to do fine-tuning, maybe you should just train your own model, which in its training set includes all the words/senses you need, from the start?